# SIP call using C# and Objective-C

Tags: c#, objective-c, sip, pjsip

I am planning to do a SIP video conferencing application that works on SIP protocol ,
between an iPhone client and C# server ?
Is that possible and is there example on C# server for handling SIP?

Answer (score 3):

Yes http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Given that SIP is a network protocol, any SIP entities implemented in any language will be able to communicate. So your Objective-C and C# stacks will happily communicate with, say, a [Delphi](https://github.com/frankshearar/SipStack) stack.